Is identity the consciousness or merely something emerging into consciousness by its close proximity to the intelligence and its process?
In the study of consciousness. The self (the identity that watches and listens, has opinions, makes comments).
This self may say, "I am the consciousness that is intelligent because I think. I hear my own thoughts. I make decisions." Are these evidence of witnessing intelligence or being the intelligence?
Thoughts come to us fully formed: organized as sentences or fully understood whole concepts where we listen and wait to see how we feel about the suggested thing. Aren't both parts just a fly on the wall observing processes inside of a consciousness? When we think suddenly, "I want strawberries," the thing that is me didn't generate that thought. It was handed to me. I was given a conceptual that was fully organized, whose origin is unknown.
If I was not thinking of strawberries, who is the who that was? What formed its idea into a meaningful structure to hand over to me, via interruption into my current thinking process, where I can now decide which questions matter regarding it? I can decide if I agree with this idea (agree with who?). I can say, "Yes, I like that idea. I want to act on it before I forget."
Aren't these, along with the others, like listening to our thoughts, waiting to see how I feel about a concept, evidences that it is not ME who is doing the thinking? Not me that is generating the manipulative statement that seems designed to encourage some kind of immediate action. Are we some "ride along" or symbiotic invited to lean consciousness. or some happenstantial emergent process that's becoming by being at some critical hub in the information exchange process of the thing we call the unconsciousness?

Consider looking in to Nonduality and Advaita Vedanta. The Abhidharma would also be informative.

"I make decisions". Many decisons have already been made before they reach consciousness, and don't need a conscious decision. Trivial examples are when to take a breath or make a heart beat. I was walking across a road at a curve with a poor line of sight. I broke into a run, and only after did I realise that I had heard a car approaching unseen. Which it did.

@WeatherVane yes, it could cause us to call in to question this "I" thing. Still, life is interesting.

@ScottRowe in my trivial examples we can decide when to take a breath, and I've read that some (vanishingly few) people learn to control their heart rate.

@WeatherVane yes, I have had some success in calming and slowing my heart using techniques from my meditation practice. (I have a "heart condition", so it calls attention to itself.) Observing and modifying breath are core to many meditation methods. So, the boundary of volition and awareness can be pushed backwards and forwards and with the same processes in the body. It is really fascinating. More people should study it.

The O.P. is using the word "consciousness" in a way that is not consistent with how the word is normally used in contemporary philosophy.  In that normal usage, "consciousness" means "the having of experience". It does not refer to the "self" that is the presumed haver of those experiences. (Such questions as the O.P. asks might be addressed under the subject of "personal identity".)

+1 To @Rushi's comment. Though I find the phrasing of the questions a bit careless, I do hope it won't be closed by people with myopic opinions about what is opinion-based and what not.

+1 @mudskipper. Yes the phrasing is clunky. How could it be otherwise? The question pertains to the hairbreath gap between me and what's most intimate to me. A gap too fine for our language to enter. [Reminds me toward "Camel in a needle"]

My question is not addressed to students of the study of The schools of philosophy. It is, in itself, a philosophical question seeking the contemplative intelligence of the students of philosophy as a collective.  I am not entirely sure that I can make or back any such disinction as a difference between the experience being had and The one having the experience. As neither can exist without the other. Even the experience itself is Framed and shaped by the Vantage point. Which is the haver's location if nothing else. As well as the haver's meaning and interpretation of sequence and concept.

One of the fundamental distinctions between eastern and western modes of philosophizing is that the former distinguishes consciousness from the content of consciousness.
By the (vanilla) western outlook, 'conscious' is always a transitive verb:

He was acutely conscious of the silence in the room
She woke conscious of a pain in her belly
I am conscious of my breath
etc

In the East, especially India, conscious(ness) is axiomatically intransitive. Examples like the above are veneers of unconsciousness plastered over pure consciousness.
Here is a brief Krishnamurti snippet that indicates that gap.
Assuming this distinction between consciousness (awareness) and the content of consciousness at least makes sense, the following
fropm Forty Verses on Reality verses 24-26 by Ramana Maharshi may hopefully be illuminating.

The inert body (which is in itself a corpse) does not say ‘I’.
Neither does pure absolute Being-Consciousness say ‘I’.
Between the two arises one mysterious thought — ‘I’.
This thought is the root of the knot of inert matter and pure Awareness.
This consciousness-inertness knot is the foundation of all:

bondage
the soul
the subtle body(s)
the ego
This is the world
This is the mind

Know this!
This mysterious X:
Holding a form it rises; holding a form it stays; holding and feeding on a form it flourishes. Leaving one form, it takes hold of another. When sought, it takes to flight. Such is this faux I-ghost, our cherished identity, this mysterious X, 1 with no form or existence of its own.
When the I-ness1 rises all things rise with it. When the I-ness is not, there is nothing else. Since this I-ness thus is everything, to question «What is this thing that says ‘I’?» is the extinction of all things.

1 Usually mistranslated as ego
With a similar message but a different voice is Gurdjieff.

Man has no individual I. But there are, instead, hundreds and thousands of separate small “I”s, very often entirely unknown to one another, never coming into contact, or, on the contrary, hostile to each other, mutually exclusive and incompatible. Each minute, each moment, man is saying or thinking, “I”. And each time his I is different. Just now it was a thought, now it is a desire, now a sensation, now another thought, and so on, endlessly. Man is a plurality. Man's name is legion
In speaking of evolution it is necessary to understand from the outset that no mechanical evolution is possible. The evolution of man is the evolution of his consciousness. And ‘consciousness’ cannot evolve unconsciously. The evolution of man is the evolution of his will, and ‘will’ cannot evolve involuntarily. The evolution of man is the evolution of his power of doing, and ‘doing’ cannot be the result of things which ‘happen.’


If you say “I am the consciousness “ then it is an incorrect perception. Consciousness is impermanent. Consciousness arises , changes (while persisting) and vanishes. Any attachment to consciousness is bound to generate suffering. And that which results in suffering can not be called Self.
If you say “I am something that emerges into consciousness “ then also it is an incorrect perception. Consciousness is impermanent. It arises , changes and vanishes. It is not proper to say that I belong to consciousness, or , consciousness is mine , or , I am part of consciousness.
There is a cooperation between brain (parts of brain) , heart , lungs , intestines , stomach , kidney , feet etc but it is wrong to say that I am any part of the body because the body and its parts and its related consciousness are impermanent. It is invalid to ask who made you say “ I want strawberries “.

This concept that consciousness is impermanent,That it vanishes. On the contratry. My own awareness did seem to emerge. I have seen consciousness vanish or appear to vanish in death. Yet the one thing that i've seen throughout my life is that consciousness is ever present. That it appearsto emerge as if it were an invisible object that becomes visible. Remaining visible then vanishing again. Yet the properties of awareness are so consistent in everything animal I interact with. That the evdence seems stronger for consciousness being potentially one of the constants
